# Like and Send Button flyout disappears

Tags: css, wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-likebox, flyout

I'm having some issues with the Facebook Like and Send button.
I'm using XFBML for the buttons, in Wordpress, Blogum theme.

But the problem is that when the Like or Send button is clicked, the flyout where you can give reactions and so on, disappears under other objects on the site.

To check it all out for yourself, see:
http://zephyrhet4e.nl/2012/06/frisse-wind/
at the bottom of the post we have the Like and Send buttons.

I would like to see that the flyout goes above all the other content on the webpage.

Is somebody able to help me with this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.post_content` class in `style.css` line 80 has `overflow:hidden`. Because your Facebook buttons are at the very bottom of your post content div, it is hiding them when they overflow its borders. Change this to `overflow:visible` and the Facebook flyouts will be visible (though you may need to check that this doesn't affect other site elements).